# PDFView does not show when presented in a root view of a navigation controller

Tags: swift, ios13, pdfkit

I have a view controller in an XIB containing a PDFView that I would like to present modally with a navigation bar and toolbar.
When presented as follows the PDFView does not appear:

```swift
    let detailVC = BackgroundImageVC(viewModel: viewModel, transparency: transparency, selector: selector)
    present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailVC), animated: true)
```

Result:

[image: Presented in navigation controller]

When presented directly the PDFView appears but of course there are no navigation and tool bars:

```swift
    let detailVC = BackgroundImageVC(viewModel: viewModel, transparency: transparency, selector: selector)
    present(detailVC, animated: true)
```

Result:

[image: Presented as view controller]

What am I missing here?

[Swift 5, Xcode 11.3.1]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add your **detailVC** as a subview.

```swift
detailVC.center = view.center
detailVC.bounds.size.width = view.bounds.width
detailVC.bounds.size.height = view.bounds.height
view.addSubview(detailVC)
```